# Button text in Upper case letters not read as words by screen readers [NVDA]

Tags: angular-material, nvda

I have a button who text should be visible in uppercase as "LOG OUT".
But, when the button gets focused using **TAB** press, NVDA screen-reader reads it as character by character as "L", "O", "G", "O","U", "T" instead of two words "LOG" and "OUT".

[Demo for the issue.](https://codepen.io/ajsun/pen/xzNMgy)

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
      <md-button tab-index="0" role="button">Log out</md-button> 
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
});
```

Comment: Try setting the `aria-label` attribute to "log out".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `aria-label` property to override the text content:

```
<md-button tab-index="0" role="button" aria-label="log out">Log out</md-button>
```